# SAS conditionally filling rows

Tags: sas

```
data have;
infile cards missover;
input scrssn :$11. year FIPS :$5.;
cards;
111-22-3333 2008 
111-22-3333 2009 
111-22-3333 2010 09990
111-22-3333 2011 
111-22-3333 2012 08880
111-22-3333 2013 
111-22-3333 2014 
333-44-5555 2009 
333-44-5555 2010 67897
333-44-5555 2011 
333-44-5555 2012 56789
333-44-5555 2013 
333-44-5555 2014 67899
333-44-5555 2015
333-44-5555 2016
333-44-5555 2017
333-44-5555 2018
;
run;
```

i would like the data

```
111-22-3333 2008 
111-22-3333 2009 
111-22-3333 2010 09990
111-22-3333 2011 09990
111-22-3333 2012 08880
111-22-3333 2013 
111-22-3333 2014 
333-44-5555 2009 
333-44-5555 2010 67897
333-44-5555 2011 67897
333-44-5555 2012 56789
333-44-5555 2013 56789
333-44-5555 2014 67899
333-44-5555 2015
333-44-5555 2016
333-44-5555 2017
333-44-5555 2018
```

For each scrssn, I would like to fill the subsequent FIPS with the previous FIPS , but stop at the last row with available FIPS

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: It's preferable if you show some code you've already written, SO isn't a code writing service.  Look into the `retain` statement, `missing` function and `first.` and `last.` by group processing. Have a go at writing the code, if it doesn't work then post what you've done and we'll help

Comment: Can you post process the code, or do you want it done into the input datastep?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
Proc Sort Data=have Out=have_sorted ;
By  scrssn;
Run;

Data test;
set have_sorted;
retain R_var ;
by scrssn;
if FIPS then r_var=Fips;
if last.scrssn then R_var='';
FIPS=R_var;
drop R_var;
run;
```

Use retain to keep the FIPS value in a new variable and then reassign it to FIPS. If it is the last by group then make the retain variable blank (missing).

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you so much!!! I just have one more question, because if I only wanted to fill the blanks in between, what if there are multiple rows for the last few observations, then i cant just simply make all the last observation empty. Thanks again!

Comment: @Daniel Luo I don't understand your question. Some clarification please, or even better, post it as a new question.